# How to make the NG Zorro modal stay opened after a promise rejection

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, ng-zorro-antd

I know you can make a modal to stay opened by returning false from nzOnOK field:

```
this.modal.confirm({
      nzTitle: 'Do you Want to delete these items?',
      nzContent: 'When clicked the OK button, this dialog will stay opened',
      nzOnOk: async () =>{
        return false;
      }
    });
```

But in my case, I have a method called from a service that might return a promise rejection or not.

I would like to make the modal stay opened if the service call fails

```
this.modal.confirm({
      nzTitle: 'Do you Want to delete these items?',
      nzContent: 'Some content',
      nzOnOk: async () =>{
        await this.myService.someMethod(); // this throws error and it should make the modal stay open
      }
    });
```

Is there a config I am missing because I don't find anything in documentation that says the modal to stay open in case of promise rejection.

Also, I don't want to use try catches or temporary variables to do this since it will defy the purpose of the rejection I am using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modal should stay opened the callback is return `false` or `Promise<false>`:

Here's an example with promise:

```
export class MyService {
  someMethod() {
    return Promise.reject();
  }
}
...
nzOnOk: () => {
   return this.myService.someMethod().then(res => !!res).catch(() => false); 
}
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tzvxpj-mgswhy?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: That's a good solution but solves half of my problem. In my case, I have some code after the promise(I await the promise then I show a success message) so I cannot return immediately :( [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tzvxpj-cmzm2o?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: This solution should work for all your cases. You just need to return Promise correctly

Comment: In your example I don't see that you're returning Promise

Comment: Yes, sorry. In my example above I don't have this case. I forgot to add it. I think I will create another question here.

The problem with this case is that I have to create some workarounds to return a promise at the end :(. I think I will use try-catch until there will be a more beautiful solution

Comment: Reproduce your issue in stackblitz please

Comment: Is the link from the first comment but here is one with a comment I added: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tzvxpj-cmzm2o?file=src/app/app.component.ts). I need to run some code after the promise is finished successfully. But I also want the modal to stay opened in case of failure

Comment: Try this one https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tzvxpj-ff9vhd?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: man, I just forgot I can use the .then from the Promise. You are a genius. I made a changes [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tzvxpj-yawf9q?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Yes, Promises are chainable